# How do I find the bias of a robust estimator of covariance and mean?

Tags: covariance, outliers, robust

I wanted to use a robust version of covariance and mean. There are many methods like the FastMCD, Olive-Hawkins and DetMCD that achieve this. However, I would like to know how biased is the the final estimate I get.

Comment: Have you had a look at [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/133782/603) answer?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following paper:
Shape Bias of Robust Covariance Estimators: An Empirical Study
M. Hubert · P. Rousseeuw · K. Vakili. 
You can grab a copy [here](https://www.google.be/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiTlNOG3v3SAhXLBBoKHbNRCWEQFggmMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwis.kuleuven.be%2Fstat%2Frobust%2Fpapers%2F2012%2Fshapebias-technicalreport.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHlukr_9UGeZVrxxQ2SLxobOF_trw)

Comment: Can you please extend your answer? What about summarizing the paper? At the moment this is rather a comment than an answer